# Using linq to retrieve pairs of Points from collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of Points, stored in a PointCollection.

I need the points in the collection to draw lines.

So, for example, if a point collection has four points, that will be three lines.

Example:

(1) Point(1,1)
(2) Point(2,2)
(3) Point(3,3)
(4) Point(4,4)

If I have a list of points, comprised of the four points referenced above, I am going to draw three lines, using the following logic:

Line 1 - Point(1,1), Point(2,2)
Line 2 - Point(2,2), Point(3,3)
Line 3 - Point(3,3), Point(4,4)

Is there a way, using Linq, Lambda Expressions, Extension Methods etc., to extract these points in pairs, from my initial list of points?  That way I can iteratively take each pair of points and draw my lines?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not know if you want to do it like that. I would: 
1) Try to get the first element, if not - throw an exception or return, otherwise save the point in a variable. 2) Until the end: get another point, draw a line, save the new point in the same var.

This keeps it sweet and simple. Use LINQ only when you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm off out in a second, but here's a *horrible* solution (in that it uses side-effects):

```
Point previous = default(Point);

return points.Select(p => { Point tmp = previous;
                            previous = p;
                            return new { p1 = tmp, p2 = previous };
                          })
             .Skip(1); // Ignore first (invalid) result
```

You can probably do better with System.Interactive and `Scan`, but otherwise it would probably be best to write a new extension method. Something like this (using `Tuple` from C# 4):

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> ConsecutivePairs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    // Omitted nullity checking; would need an extra method to cope with
    // iterator block deferred execution
    using (IEnumerator<T> iterator = sequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        T previous = iterator.Current;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(previous, iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

(Apologies for any mistakes - written in a hurry!)

Comment: I am amused how many comply with a horrible request and give a horrible solution instead of saying - you better do it this way.

Comment: It is possible, though, that there is context or other conditions not fully represented in the question that makes the solution not horrible. And you can usually count on at least one answer telling you everything that was wrong with your question.

Comment: I'm limited to a solution that is based on .NET 3.5.

Comment: @chris: it would be easy enough to create your own tuple type.